# How to count paragraphs from each article from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, text, nlp

I want to count paragraphs from data frames. However, it turns out that my result gets zero inside the list. Does anybody know how to fix it? Thank you so much.

Here is my code:

```
def count_paragraphs(df):
    paragraph_count = []
    linecount = 0
    for i in df.text:
        if i in ('\n','\r\n'):
            if linecount == 0:
                paragraphcount = paragraphcount + 1
    return paragraph_count

count_paragraphs(df)
```

df.text

```
0     On Saturday, September 17 at 8:30 pm EST, an e...
1     Story highlights "This, though, is certain: to...
2     Critical Counties is a CNN series exploring 11...
3     McCain Criticized Trump for Arpaio’s Pardon… S...
4     Story highlights Obams reaffirms US commitment...
5     Obama weighs in on the debate\n\nPresident Bar...
6     Story highlights Ted Cruz refused to endorse T...
7     Last week I wrote an article titled “Donald Tr...
8     Story highlights Trump has 45%, Clinton 42% an...
9     Less than a day after protests over the police...
10    I woke up this morning to find a variation of ...
11    Thanks in part to the declassification of Defe...
12    The Democrats are using an intimidation tactic...
13    Dolly Kyle has written a scathing “tell all” b...
14    The Haitians in the audience have some newswor...
15    The man arrested Monday in connection with the...
16    Back when the news first broke about the pay-t...
17    Chicago Environmentalist Scumbags\n\nLeftists ...
18    Well THAT’S Weird. If the Birther movement is ...
19    Former President Bill Clinton and his Clinton ...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
def count_paragraphs(df):
    return df.text.str.count(r'\n\n').tolist()
count_paragraphs(df)
```

Comment: Do you know how to count paragraphs from each article and save it to list? for instance [3,4,5] means that in index 0 there are 3 paragraphs in first article etc.

Comment: @RosyIndahPermatasari - do you think `L = df['text'].str.count('\\n').tolist()` ?

Comment: I mean counting paragraphs in each article.. not converted it to list

Comment: @RosyIndahPermatasari - Is one article one value in `Text` column?

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer and It works!

```
def count_paragraphs(df):
    paragraph_count = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        paragraph_count.append(df.text[i].count('\n\n'))
    return paragraph_count
count_paragraphs(df)
```

Comment: @jezrael This is the result I want to have [5, 7, 8, 0, 7, 12, 8, 7, 7, 14, 12, 8, 2, 9, 14, 4, 5, 9, 13, 43] Do you think loops are still not necessary? and why?

Comment: Because antipattern - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002)

Comment: @RosyIndahPermatasari - My edited answer not working?

Comment: @jezrael oh sorry! it's really working! thank you so much! my mistake :(